# Fallback for environment variables with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given the following configuration:

```
mysql:
    environment:
        MY_MYSQL_PORT:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - "${MY_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
```

There's a way to provide a fallback value for MY_MYSQL_PORT without relying on wrapper scripts? I already tested like bash ${MY_MYSQL_PORT-3306} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not yet, there's an issue open for it https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2178

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They implemented that feature with compose 1.9 release:

> Added support for shell-style inline defaults in variable interpolation.
>
> The supported forms are ${FOO-default} (fall back if FOO is unset) and ${FOO:-default} (fall back if FOO is unset or empty).

[Release Notes Docker Compose 1.9](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.9.0)

Answer (score 8):

An explanation in the Dockerfile documentation can be found at:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

To quote from there:

The `${variable_name}` syntax also supports a few of the standard bash modifiers as specified below:

- `${variable:-word}` indicates that if `variable` is set then the result will be that value. If `variable` is not set then `word` will be the result.
- `${variable:+word}` indicates that if `variable` is set then `word` will be the result, otherwise the result is the empty string.

In all cases, word can be any string, including additional environment variables.

Escaping is possible by adding a `\` before the variable: `\$foo` or `\${foo}`, for example, will translate to $foo and ${foo} literals respectively.

Comment: thx for prettifying the markup